# Shrinkage in hierarhical models based not on observations

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, hierarchical-bayesian, regularization

When we have a hierarchical model, such as:

$$log(y_{i,t})=\beta_0 + \beta_i*log(x_{i,t})+\epsilon_{i,t}$$

Where $\beta_i$ ~ $N(B,\Sigma)$, and the sampling model is normal (normal disturbances.)

We induce shrinkage in $\beta_i$ towards the population coefficient $B$.  The fewer observations per "group," the more shrinkage will occur.

I currently am working with a data set that is at the group weekly level, and the groups are stores.  I am running a $log(y+1)$ on $log(x)$ regression to recover elasticities.   Some groups have a lot of $x$ variation, and some have very little.  The stores that have a lot of $x$ variation end up giving reasonable elasticities, the ones that have little end up with wacky ones (positive, etc).

However, since the panel is balanced, all units have the same number of observations, so the weird ones aren't getting shrunk anymore than the sensible ones!

Is there any sort of variance-in-X-based shrinkage?  Or is that excessively complicated to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already does this:

It is a weighted average of the OLS coefficient on the group and the population parameter $B$.

The weights correspond to not only sample size, but to the variance in X:

$$w*B + (1-w)*\hat{\beta}$$

Where

$$w = \dfrac{\Sigma_{0}^{-1}}{\Sigma_{0}^{-1}+\dfrac{X_{j}^{\prime}X_{j}}{\sigma^{2}}}$$

Furthermore, $X_{j}^{\prime}X_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{i}^{\prime}$,

So the lower the variance in X, the lower this quantity will be, but the higher $n$, the higher this quantity will be.